# PHP script prints directly onto webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

MyPHP code that I wrote keeps printing everything that I wrote onto the web page.
Here is a picture:

[image]

And here is the source code:

```
<?php
   define('DB_NAME', 'reg_form');
   define('DB_USER', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
   define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

    if (!db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME ': ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Thanks.
- Hayes Derbyshire

Comment: Do I sense a mis-configured apache handler? I think so

Comment: Since PHP is a server side language, you have to set up a web server to interpret the PHP and display HTML in the browser. You can't point directly to the PHP file in your browser.

Comment: So, how can I configure it properly???

Comment: you are accesing it as a file not as a URL. The php has to be evaluated by a web server to give the correct output. Access it with http://....

Comment: see **file://** in the browser, no web-server there

Comment: I think the first issue is that you're using Windows, just throwing that out there ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your opening your code directly in your browser instead of running it through a web server.  You can either upload your code to a web server that supports PHP or install one on your computer.  I would recommend looking at XAMPP from http://www.apachefriends.org I've used this project for development many times and it is quick and easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

You're are opening file - so it's shows it content. You need move this document to localhost root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're opening a local .php file into your web browser? That's why it's displaying the text within the file.

If you're wanting this to run, it'll need to be hosted server-side and called, probably through html, for it to be ran and displayed.

Consider downloading [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). It's a server program you can use to work on these kinds of projects while staying local.

Hope this helps!